# When I am trying to dynamically add new tab in QTabWidget my UI freezes and crashes afterwards I don't know whats going on

Tags: python, break, tabwidget

What I want to when I click the new Tab (pushButton4) button it should add a new tab in QTabWidget. I tried googling it .. it showed me the same syntax so I have no clue where its breaking the code. The syntax I got from google but I dont know wheather it is proper or not. 
This is my code to add new tab please have a look and let me know if it is proper or not. Thanks.

```
 `self.pushButton_4.clicked.connect(self.addTabs)`

 `self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tabWidget,"tab3")`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was simple rather than trying to add just string add a widget.

```
self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tabWidget,"tab3")
```

So I tried

```
self.tabWidget.addTab(QtGui.QWidget(),QString('New Tab'))
```

which creates a new tab. Find more reference at [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qwidget.html)